# Delta lake zones storage

Tags: delta-lake

I have these questions on delta lake physical storage:

1. When we create Delta tables in Enriched zone, does it point to the
   data already stored in the Raw zone?  Or will it create a new
   separate (which is redundant probably) physical copy of data?
2. Let suppose, my Raw zone now contains 950 TB of total data - only 150 TB
   of which resides on hot-tier (for business purpose), and the rest
   800 TB resides in archive-tier (for compliance/audit purpose) of the
   Raw zone (in the Data Lake).  A new batch of data comes in (let say
   1 GB in size).  It represents new data mostly, but also has some
   updates to the existing data.  How should I accommodate this batch?
   I can easily dump new data in the Raw zone (in appropriate
   partitioned folder structure), but should I update Raw zone to
   update the existing ones from the new batch?  But is not the Raw
   zone read-only, append-only?  I think I'm not getting 100% the under
   the hood part (like how and where data stored physically within
   these zones, etc.) of all this.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the recent seminars I attended, I believe I got the answer to the question #1 at the least.  Here it's JIC:

Yes, Delta tables created in the Silver (Enriched) zone will reference the data stored physically in the Bronze (Raw) zone.  So no data duplication is happening here. They leverage the underlying Parquet files in the Bronze zone. Delta tables in the Silver zone maintain schema and metadata while referencing Parquet data files in the Bronze zone and keeping track of changes.